# what does NCC stand for?

Tags: linux

I am studying a Redis course. In the course, the instructor says that `"Redis was written in NCC, which makes it friendly with Unix-based systems like Mac or Linux without any other dependencies"`

I've google what NCC stands for and all I could find is that ncc is a code analysis tool. This doesn't fit in the context here..

So what exactly is ncc and how it relates to unix environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google says Redis was written in ANSI C

NCC ("Enn See See") sounds similar to "Ansi C", I suspect this is a [Mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)

Comment: aaa. you are correct. The course comes with a transcript with NCC in it, but apparently no one double checked it.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Internet, Redis was written in ANSI C, which sounds similar to NCC.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/260185)

Comment: Ok, understood.

Comment: No, this ***does*** provide an answer to the question.  The only problems are (1) you didn’t *explicitly* say “probably your instructor said ‘ANSI C’ and you misheard” (but that’s fairly obvious), and (2) somebody else posted an equivalent answer before you.  Since the time interval was less than three minutes,  most people will assume that you came up with your answer independently and typed it while the other person was typing theirs (i.e., most people will assume that you ***didn’t*** copy the other answer).  So this is fine.

Comment: P.S. “The Internet” is not a source —  you should post an actual reference (i.e., a link) if possible.

Comment: Ah okok I get it :) next time I'll be more specific.

Comment: Hey, your answer was great! Thank you. I checked the top one, since it was first